# how can I pass an array pointer to a function

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

typedef vector <double> record_t;
typedef vector <record_t> data_t;


int sorted(int *data,int max_record_size)
{


}




int main()
{
    // Here is the data we want.
    data_t data;

    // Here is the file containing the data. Read it into data.
    ifstream infile( "sort.txt" );
    infile >> data;

    // Complain if something went wrong.
    if (!infile.eof())
    {
        cout << "Fooey!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    infile.close();

    // Otherwise, list some basic information about the file.
    cout << "Your CSV file contains " << data.size() << " records.\n";



    unsigned max_record_size = 0;
    for (unsigned n = 0; n < data.size(); n++)
        if (max_record_size < data[ n ].size())
            max_record_size = data[ n ].size();
    cout << "The largest record has " << max_record_size << " fields.\n";
    int i;
    for (i=0; i <= max_record_size; i++)
    {

        cout << "your data contains " << data[ 0 ][ i ] << ".\n";
        int temp[max_record_size];

        sorted(&data,max_record_size);

        //cout << "Your sorted data contains" << sorted [0] [i] << ".\n";
    }


    cout << "Good bye!\n";
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

> cannot convert `data_t*' to`int*' for argument `1' to`int
>   sorted(int*, int)'

Im trying to pass the pointer of my data which should be an array containing my list of numbers to my sort function what exactly am I doing wrong and can you please explain in detail so I can understand it, thanks!

Comment: your indentation is so ridiculous I'm not even going to try to fix it.  please clean up your code block.

Comment: You're trying to use a `data_t*` as an `int*`. If you're sure they are the same data type, do a cast.

Comment: `data` is a list of `ints`? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an array. An array in C (or C++) would be just a list of integers, and you could pass it like you did.

However, you have a vector (and I'm guessing record_t ends up being an int). vector<>s behave a lot like arrays, but they are not, they are actual objects.

What you probably want to do is write your function as

```
int sorted(data_t& data, int max_record_size)
```

and your call simply as

```
sorted(data,max_record_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

`data_t` is a `vector<vector<double>>`. This is not even close to an array of ints. You just need to write a function that handles data_t and not ints.

If the function is supposed to sort `data` then you should use `std::sort`, and to do that you'll need to write a comparison function that can compare two elements of `data` in order to see which one should come before the other in the sorted result.

Here's an example of providing such a comparison function using a lambda with lexicographical_compare.

```
sort(begin(data),end(data), [](record_t const &lhs,record_t const &rhs) {
    return lexicographical_compare(begin(lhs),end(lhs),begin(rhs),end(rhs));]
});
```

Comment: Nah, what's needed is a comparison function to pass to std::sort, along with the .begin() and .end() iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a **`reference`** to the original vector. Why?

- You still want to work with the original vector without making a copy
- You can't pass a `null` reference, so the argument is always valid
- You're not doing any pointer arithmetic, so be safe and use a **`reference`**

  ```
  int sorted(data_t& data, int max_record_size)
  {             
  }
  ```

Pass your `data_t` structure like this:

```
sorted(data, max_record_size);
```

Now you have access to the data_t structure inside your `sorted` function.

**Also**

You know that your code is not going to compile?

- `unsigned max_record_size` and `int temp[max_record_size]` are invalid. If you're going to allocate an array on the stack, you need to use a constant size.
- There is no overload on the `>>` operator in the `istream` class that handles `vector<vector<double>>`, so this statement is broken as well: `infile >> data;`

Comment: The code complies and reads in the text files and stores it in data. So I can iterate through the entire list but I want to pass a pointer to the vector to a different function. I tried int sorted(vector<int> &data, int max_record_size) but it's giving me errors

Comment: You must have an awesome compiler. You can pass your `data_t` to any function, see my changes.

Comment: thanks that works! can you explain why the function prototype takes data_t& data as a parameter I'm not very clear on this.

Comment: You should read more about `pointer` and `references`. See my edits to start. I'm glad this solution works for you.